# MySQL SELECT returns empty set when there is data

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT title FROM pages WHERE id=111;
+------------+
| title      |
+------------+
| 'Theology' |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM pages WHERE title='Theology';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The results conflicted. I can't understand that.

Comment: How about SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title = 'Theology' then try with Like. The * selects the whole records instead of just the id

Comment: its working .....you should check it again http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5d3a/4

Comment: `'Theology' <> Theology` so you may need `where title = '\'Theology\''`

Comment: Wow, the last method helped! Thank you Abhik!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
'Theology'
```

to

```
'\'Theology\''
```

Seems that the data stored is **'Theology'** instead of **Theology**. Thanks to Abhik Chakraborty.

Answer (score 0):

Use query like this . You need to escape the `'`

1st Way

```
SELECT id FROM pages WHERE title = '\'Theology\''
```

2nd Way

```
SELECT id FROM pages WHERE title = "'Theology'"
```

3rd Way

```
SELECT id FROM pages WHERE title='''Theology''';
```